# Printing bootstrap 4 HTML page in Chrome cuts off chrome header/footers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with printing an HTML page styled with Bootstrap 4 (only 4, 3.3.7 works fine) from Chrome where the header and footer are partly covered up. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryHlk.jpg)  is a screenshot of what I'm referring to, you'll see the date, title, file/url are partly cut off. It seems be an issue with bootstrap. I created a small test page with nothing but a link to the bootstrap cdn and it still happens.

Here is the HTML as a test:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you put that into an html page and then open it in chrome and right-click -> print, you should see the same results.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I am having similar issue, but I'm not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the [size property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) is set to **a3** in the full bootstrap css file (not the [grid or reboot](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files)) in version 4.1.1 (most recent version at time of writing)

to fix add following snippet:

```
@page {
    size: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is what solved the issue for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than include an additional `@page { size: auto; }` rule override the `$print-page-size: auto;` variable before importing the bootstrap scss file:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this rule in bootstrap's `_print.scss` seems to be the culprit:

```
// Specify a size and min-width to make printing closer across browsers.
// We don't set margin here because it breaks `size` in Chrome. We also
// don't use `!important` on `size` as it breaks in Chrome.
@page {
  size: $print-page-size;
}
```

Although the code comments say that "margin...breaks `size` in Chrome," I didn't find that to be the case. Setting margins, rather than changing the size property directly, preserves bootstrap's other helpful page formatting. A `margin-top` rule pushes content below the page header (date and title), and a `margin-bottom` one clears the page footer (url and page #).

```
@page {
  margin-top: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```